# Is it possible to tell the php interpreter to ignore code blocks?

Tags: php, interpreter, opcache

## Background

Back in the day when I did C programing we used assume statements to make sure the code was healthy. Something like:

```
aFunction(int hello)
{
  assume(hello < 10);
```

The cool thing about the assume statement is it was defined to be an empty macro for release compiling and a die on false statement on debug compiling. So the developer had all the benefits of an assert statement checking their assumptions without causing unnecessary bugs or affecting performance in

## Problem

Now that I'm working php I'm looking for a similar mechanism. I currently have my assume statement looking something like this:

```
define(DEBUG, getenv('debug'));
function assume($a)
{
  if (DEBUG && !$a)
  {
    echo 'ASSUME FAILURE <br />';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
    die('<pre>');
  }
}
assume($a == $b);
```

As you can see I set the debug flag in the server settings to remove the actual die statement and such. However a function call is still performed and an if statement is still evaluated. This is not a big deal if it only occurs a few thousand times but as the code get's bigger and as these assumes get put into loops this could have a legitimate affect on performance.

## Question

Is there a way to tell the interpreter or opcache (I'm currently using zend opcache included in php 5.5) to ignore these assume statements altogether? or is there another method of handling this problem?

Comment: Short answer.  Keep your unit tests adjacent to your actual code, not mixed into it.  It clutters things and adds overhead.  Sure you could clean it up as part of some CI process.. but well, there are best practices out there for tests and PHP, follow them.

Comment: Are you familiar with PHPUnit? Nowadays, this would really be better handled with a test suite that verifies aspects of your code, rather than your code self-verifying https://phpunit.de/

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Unit Testing is a very different use case from assume statements. I would love to put together some unit testing someday but it does not replace a simple assume.

Comment: PHP is more about 'runtime' as, on any day, it can get very 'dynamic'. However, there is nothing preventing you from using: [assert — Checks if assertion is FALSE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php), to do 'sanity' checks wherever you wish. They can be very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the C compiler is optimized and can eliminate blocks of code that are not used. In PHP, `assume` is a function call, and the function has to exist.

A couple of solutions. First, you may use [`assert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php). The `assert` function works similar to your own `assume` function. If an assertion fails, a defined assertion handler is called. You can easily enable or disable assertions, and if you disable them, the assertion handler is not called at all.

If you want to proceed with your own `assume` function, you can still optimize it a little, by declaring the function based on the define:

```
<?php
define(DEBUG, getenv('debug'));

if (DEBUG) {
  function assume($a) {
    echo 'ASSUME FAILURE <br />';
    echo '<pre>';
    echo print_r(debug_backtrace());
    die('<pre>');
  }
} else {
  function assume($x) {}
}
```

This way, you actually declare `assume` as an empty function. The comment by Michael Berkowski confirms my fear that PHP doesn't eliminate the call completely, but at least you save the `if`.

Another solution is to call assume a little more complex:

```
DEBUG && assume($x < 10);
```

This way, if DEBUG is false, the call is not made at all. This way only the boolean value is evaluated, and no function call is made. Of course, calling it this way is a bit harder and less readable, but I think the savings of not calling a function are much more significant than eliminating an `if`.

Comment: It doesn't look like PHP nullifies an empty function definition, which in this test runs about 2-3x slower than a no-op.  Still, this is a cool solution. http://3v4l.org/7XQMV

Comment: I think the assert does what I was looking for. I didn't realize it could be configured to not execute.

Comment: In terms of the `DEBUG && assume($x < 10)` approach, after 5.6 if you have enabled the OPcache optimizer, then this does constant folding and will eliminate `if (FALSE)` type expressions so long as the constant is defined at compile time (that is in a previously compiled module).